# Why isn't OrientDB EXPORT command maintaining the clusters

Tags: database, orientdb

I am trying to make an exact copy of an OrientDB database.

So I am exporting the copied database and then creating a new database and importing everything from the export file.

All of the schema and records are correctly imported, but the records in the new database are not in the same clusters as the old database. Instead the records are spread evenly into the class's different clusters.

---

eg. If I have the dog, dog_1, dog_2, dogs clusters and 8 dog records.

In the old database I'll have

```
dog = 0 members
dog_1 = 0 members
dog_2 = 0 members
dogs = 8 members
```

---

Once I create the new database from the export file the result is:

```
dog = 2 members
dog_1 = 2 members
dog_2 = 2 members
dogs = 2 members
```

---

I am using this command to export the database

```
EXPORT DATABASE dummyexport.export
```

I am using this command to create and import the new database

```
CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/PleaseWorkDB root 123 plocal
IMPORT DATABASE dummyexport.export.gz -preserveClusterIDs=true
```

.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-preserveClusterIDs` is not supported anymore. Your application shouldn't rely on RIDs. They are like persistent pointers, but in case of export/reimport they could change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-preserveClusterIDs` import option because in this way you can define whether you want to preserve cluster ID's during the import. When turned off, the import creates temporary cluster ID's, which can sometimes fail. This option is only valid with PLocal storage.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Import.html

Hope it helps

Regards